# Is it possible for Thread 2 to print “x=0”?

Tags: java

Is it possible for Thread 2 to print “x=0”?

```
int x = 0;
boolean bExit = false;

Thread 1 (not synchronized)
x = 1; 
bExit = true;

Thread 2 (not synchronized)
if (bExit == true) 
System.out.println("x=" + x);
```

Comment: Yes it is possible - as there are no shown/implied happens-before relations established. (Although more complete code should generally be included in such question, preferably that which runs.)

Comment: @Dhaval: Pls accept the answer if your question is answered.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible for Thread 2 to print “x=0”?

**Yes** if instructions are reordered by the JIT compiler as:

**Thread1:**

```
bExit=true
x=1
```

**Thread2:**

```
 if (bExit == true) System.out.println("x=" + x); //prints 0
```

When you use synchronized block (or other related constructs) the instrcutions are not reordered by the compiler.

Comment: It might be worth emphasizing that this would be the JIT compiler, not javac.

Comment: why would thread1's instruction change order? I could not understand the answer, can you add more details please?

Comment: CPU could also re-order instructions.

Comment: can CPU re-order instructions internal to a thread? I guess it is always sequential in a given block.

Comment: And what about caching? If both threads run on different processors and `Thread 2` read `x` previously, then even without rearranging the order of instructions, `Thread 2` can read that `x==0`, right?

Comment: @MohitKanwar - not on x86, I think. but some architecture has weaker memory model, so writes may appear out-of-order.

Comment: @kajacx - definitely; or it can be said that the read of `x` is re-ordered

Comment: @kajacx I guess, if caching is used, it would be there for both the variables. so both the variables would be picked from cache and hence previous values.

Answer (score 2):

Answer : Yes, It's possible that thread T2 may print x=0.Why? because without any instruction to compiler e.g. synchronized or volatile, bExit=true might come before x=1 in compiler reordering. Also x=1 might not become visible in Thread 2, so Thread 2 will load x=0. Now, how do you fix it? When I asked this question to couple of programmers they answer differently, one suggest to make both thread synchronized on a common mutex, another one said make both variable volatile. Both are correct, as it will prevent reordering and guarantee visibility. But best answer is you just need to make bExit as volatile, then Thread 2 can only print “x=1”. x does not need to be volatile because x cannot be reordered to come after bExit=true when bExit is volatile.